# Python Sort One List According to Another List

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have two lists, the first list is the key order, the second list is a tuple list.

```
colorOrder = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green']
tupleList = [(111,'red'),(222,'pink'),(333,'green')]
```

Please notice the two lists are not one-to-one relationship. Some colors are not in `colorOrder`, and some colors in `colorOrder` never appear in `tupleList`. So It is different from other similiar duplicate problems.

I need to Sort the tupleList according to the colorOrder.

I can solve this problem using two nested for loops, but need a more efficient solution.

```
#First sort according to the color order
    for aColor in colorOrder:
        for aTuple in tupleList:
            if aTuple[1] == aColor:
                ResultList.append(aTuple)
#Second add the tuples to the ResultList, whose color is not in the colorOrder
    for aTuple in tupleList:
        if aTuple[1] not in colorOrder:
            ResultList.append(aTuple)
```

Comment: When you write that you need to sort "the `tupleList` according to the `colorOrder`", do you meant that a tupleList entry should come first if its corresponding string comes earlier in `colorOrder`? E.g. sorting the example you give should yield `[(111,'red'),(333,'green'),(222,'pink')]`?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Yes, you understand it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I'd make `colorOrder` a mapping:

```
colorMap = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(colorOrder)}
```

Now sorting becomes a bit easier with `colorMap.get`

```
sorted(tupleList, key=lambda tup: colorMap.get(tup[1], -1))
```

This puts things not in the map *first*.  If you'd rather add them *last*, just use a really big number:

```
sorted(tupleList, key=lambda tup: colorMap.get(tup[1], float('inf')))
```

Comment: Actually, first I would change all the `namesLikeThis` to `names_like_this` as that is more typical naming convention for python ;-).  _Then_ I'd make the mapping ...

Comment: The `float('inf')` can be replaced by `len(colorOrder)`?

Comment: @JamesKing -- Sure, if you prefer that :-)  It really doesn't make a difference one way or another.  I prefer infinity because when I see it, I immediately know that it's gonna be at the end of the list.  I see a `len(something)` and then I have to start thinking...

Answer (score 0):

Check this Solution:

```
     xx = dict([(x[1],x[0]) for x in enumerate(colorOrder)])
     [x[1] for x in sorted([(xx.get(y[1],999),y) for y in tupleList])]
```